# Styling very long index entries to look more aesthetic

Tags: formatting, indexing

I wrote the following style for `makeindex`:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
delim_0 " \\dotfill "
delim_1 " \\dotfill "
delim_2 " \\dotfill "
```

which works pretty good. It happens that I have some very long index entries, and their display is not what I expected. This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
Hello.\index{Hello}
Hello again.\index{Hello again}
Hi there.\index{Hello there, this is a very long text here}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

When I run `makeindex mwe.idx -s mystyle.ist`, this is the output:

[image: Index 1]

To be honest, I was expecting something like this:

[image: Index 2]

I tried to find some help on styles in *The LaTeX Companion* book, but I could not assimilate much. I'm relying on the belief that I could solve this by using a proper `ist` file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your belief is correct -- use the style file `gind.ist`.

EDIT: Or try to change your custom file `mystyle.ist` as follows:

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries "
heading_suffix "}\\nopagebreak\n"
item_x1   "\\efill \n \\subitem "
item_x2   "\\efill \n \\subsubitem "
delim_0   "\\pfill "
delim_1   "\\pfill "
delim_2   "\\pfill "
```

Comment: Thanks, lockstep! But for some reason, when I try to compile it again, it raises `! Undefined control sequence. l.3  \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse`. Do I need to set anything else?

Comment: @Paulo: `\scan@allowedfalse` is indeed part of `gind.ist`. Try to delete all auxiliary files and then compile again.

Comment: Sadly, for some reason, it didn't work. I'm gonna try it again and see if I discover what's happening in my (La)TeX kingdom. `=)`

Comment: Found it! There's a nice explanation in [this](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2009-12/msg00906.html) `comp.text.tex` thread: "`gind.ist` is meant to be used with the class `ltxdoc`. It requires certain macros only defined in `doc.sty` (loaded by `ltsdoc.cls`)." I'll study those macros and see if I can come up with something. `=)`

Comment: @Paulo: Sorry for the misleading first version of my answer.

Comment: Don't worry, my friend. `=)` We both learned something new about `gind.ist`. Your new solution works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @Paulo: Could you share your solution. I am having the same problem with my index that you describe. Adding locksteps solution directly does not work my me as it did not work for you.

Comment: @swiper: I fixed an error in the `makeindex` line, it should be `mwe.idx` instead of `mwe.tex` as stated previously. That said, I had problems with `\efill` and `\pfill` myself, but [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23374/pfill-probably-conflicting-with-other-commands-or-packages/23375#23375) helped me a lot.