# \pfill probably conflicting with other commands or packages

Tags: indexing

Friends, I'm stuck with the following issue: I have a document with several indices. The `splitidx` package deals with them with no problems. It happens that I have some very long index entries, so I decided to make them look more aesthetic:

[Styling very long index entries to look more aesthetic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23320/styling-very-long-index-entries-to-look-more-aesthetic)

**lockstep** provided an [amazing solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23320/styling-very-long-index-entries-to-look-more-aesthetic/23323#23323) that works like a charm. This solution works in my other documents. Unfortunately, when I try to use it in my "production document", it does not work. **egreg** suggested me to reduce my document to a minimal example, so here it is. Thankfully it still does not work:

```
% since the first example was full of "package noise",
% I left only the needed ones.
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{savesym}

\usepackage[useindex]{splitidx}
\savesymbol{newindex}
\makeindex
\orignewindex[My custom index]{stl}
\AtWriteToIndex{stl}{\let\thepage\thesongnum}

\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

\newindex{reltitleidx}{cbreltitle}

\begin{document}

\showindex{{\normalfont\bfseries My songs index}}{reltitleidx}

\begin{songs}{reltitleidx}

\beginsong{Funny song}[by={},sr={}]

\sindex[stl]{Cool@\textbf{Cool}!Stuff}

\beginchorus
This is my chorus.
\endchorus

\beginverse
Verse 1.
\endverse

\beginverse
Verse 2.
\endverse

\beginverse
Verse 3.
\endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}

\printindex*

\end{document}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** I forgot to mention. `\pfill` seems to raise the errors. If I remove it from my `ist` style file, the document is successfully compiled.

There are the commands: `pdflatex mydocument.tex`, `splitindex mydocument.idx`, `makeindex -s mystyle.ist mydocument-stl.idx`, `pdflatex mydocument.tex`.

**EDIT 2:** Errors raised:

> `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \efill l.4 \item
>   \textbf{Cool}\efill`

and

> `! Undefined control sequence. \pfill ...ll
>   \penalty 500 \strut \nobreak \dotfil ~\ignorespaces l.5 \subitem
>   Stuff\pfill 1`

**EDIT 3:** I owe **egreg** a drink. The first error is gone! The index is properly generated, but this annoying error still bugs me:

> `! Undefined control sequence. \pfill ...ll \penalty 500 \strut
>   \nobreak \dotfil 
>   ~\ignorespaces  l.5 
>   \subitem Stuff\pfill 1`

**EDIT 4:** It's now solved, thanks to **egreg**'s fantastic solution. `=)`

**EDIT 5:** For completeness sake, my style file is based on `gind.ist`. Since those commands were not defined in terms of others, the above errors raised. Once you correctly define them, the errors are gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\pfill` is a macro from **ltxdoc**

```
\def\pfill{\unskip~\dotfill\penalty500 
  \strut\nobreak\leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss.\hss}\hfil~\ignorespaces}
```

You might need also `\efill`:

```
\def\efill{\hfill\nopagebreak}
```

`\dotfil` is defined just as

```
\def\dotfil{\leaders\hbox to.6em{\hss.\hss}\hfil}
```

Comment: Thanks, egreg! But for some reason, it still does not work. Two errors were raised: `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \efill l.4   \item \textbf{Cool}\efill` and `! Undefined control sequence. \pfill ...ll \penalty 500 \strut \nobreak \dotfil ~\ignorespaces l.5  \subitem Stuff\pfill 1`. Did it work for you?

Comment: Thanks! Now one of the errors is gone! It works (my index is displayed correctly), but this error is still raised: `! Undefined control sequence. \pfill ...ll \penalty 500 \strut \nobreak\dotfil \ignorespaces l.5  \subitem Stuff\pfill 1`. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the undefined control sequence? It's the last in the first line of the error message.

Comment: I think it's `l.5  \subitem Stuff\pfill`. The last line has only a `1`. `=P`

Answer (score 1):

Paulo: Regarding your MWE -- I had to change the four `\renewcommand{\idx...}` commands to `\newcommand` and also had to comment out the `\songpos` command (line 50) as it doesn't seem to be defined in songs.sty. After running the MWE through latex and makeindex, the following text shows up in the song.ilg file:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2011] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file song.idx...
!! Input index error (file = song.idx, line = 1):
   -- Unknown index keyword \indexentry[stl].
done (0 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Nothing written in song.ind.
Transcript written in song.ilg.
```

Is this the error you're getting as well?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, the four `\renewcommand` commands are optional. `=)` I just kept them for testing purposes. The CTAN version of `songs` is very outdated, the one I use is the last stable one available [here](http://songs.sourceforge.net/). Anyway, I updated my question and put the errors I'm getting. I'm running `splitindex` then `makeindex`. The errors seem not to be in those parsers per se (nothing is rejected, and if I keep the default style for `makeindex`, everything works), but in my source itself. `=(`